# UINavigationBar is not showing despite being embedded in NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have my ViewControllers embedded in a Navigation Controller, however when I run the app the navigation bar doesn't appear, instead appears as follows:

[image]

This is however how my VC in the storyboard looks:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea on why might this be happening?

Kind regards - thanks in advance!

Comment: Show a screen shot of the relevant part of the storyboard, please.

Comment: @matt Tell me exactly what you wanna see.

Comment: Oh, also: there is no visible status bar any more, so you have to ask yourself, what is that blurry rectangle behind the status bar? That must be something _you are creating_. You need to look for where that is being done.

Comment: :) Ideally you could just post the project where I can download it and I'll figure it out for you. Describing or even screen-shotting a storyboard is a big hassle, I know.

Comment: @matt You can download it from there, just make sure to bypass the LogIn to be able to segue to the screen that shows the issue.

Comment: Isn't the problem simply that the login view controller is saying `self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true`?

Comment: @matt Yeah, but that only applies to the LoginVC, not the other one. The other one is the one in which I need the bar.

Comment: But once you've hidden it, you've hidden it. Do you see? You hide it initially, and then you never show it. So it never shows. It isn't going to come back all by itself!

Comment: @matt Uppps. You are right, I thought that after the segue it would appear by itself. I´m really sorry for the stupid question. Thank you very much though!

Comment: Don't be sorry, it was easy to look and discover the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if your navigation bar is not hidden, you can do it by `isNavigationBarHidden` on UINavigationController instance. You can set this value either in storyboard or in code by calling `setNavigationBarHidden(_ hidden: Bool, animated: Bool)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try and Drag Navigation Item to the navigation bar from the storyboard. It worked for me. If not, try setting constraints for the navigation bar. I know it sounds random, but that's how I solved this issue most of the times.